# Pandas to_numeric is not downcasting integer column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column with `dtype('int64')`.  The values in the column range from 0-10.  The dataframe has 770K rows and 56 columns of different types.  When I run the code below, I get `dtype('int64')`.  I would have thought that the result would have been at a minimum to downcast to `int32` or `int16`. Here's a replicable example.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([x for x in range(10)]*77000, columns=['recommendation'])
df.dtypes
df.recommendation.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, downcast='integer')).dtypes
```

Comment: try `pd.to_numeric(df.recommendation,downcast='integer').dtypes`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method works cell-by-cell, so it cannot figure out that the whole column can be downcast.
You need to call [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) on the whole column, as indicated by Ben in comment:

```
pd.to_numeric(df.recommendation,downcast='integer')
```